# Принятия к исполнению *постановлени(е/я)*?

Tags: падежи, родительный-или-винительный

"Организация сообщает о принятии к исполнению *постановлени(е)* или *постановлени(я)*?"

Какое должно быть окончание у слова в единственном числе и как определить правильно падеж - родительный или винительный?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Как ни читай, а падеж будет родительный, то есть

*Организация сообщает о принятии к исполнению постановлени**я**.*

Определяет падеж управление.

О принятии - чего? - постановления. К исполнению - чего? - постановления.

---

P. S.

#### Чтобы определить падеж существительного, нужно:

1. Найти слово, от которого зависит существительное.
2. От этого слова к существительному поставить вопрос.
3. По вопросу и предлогу определить падеж.

> Обратим внимание, что вопрос должен быть падежным, а не смысловым. По
>   вопросам где? куда? когда? почему? определить падеж не получится.

Answer (score 0):

О принятии чего или о принятии что? О принятии подарок... о принятии решение?!